# My FastAPI Docker Contaner Is Not Reading Changes to My .env File

Tags: python, docker-compose, fastapi, .env

RESOLVED: 1. I added the new environmental variable to the docker-compose.yaml file, so docker knows to load that environmental variable.
2. The .env file is read by docker-compose. In order for changes to the .env file to be read, the containers must be spun up from the command line using docker-compose up.

---

I added a third environmental variable to my workspace's .env file, deleted my Docker containers and images, and rebuilt the images using the --no-cache flag. Yet when I go into my container's terminal in Docker and echo $VARIABLE_NAME, it comes back empty. The first two environmental variables continue to echo back their expected values.

I’ve also discovered that if I delete the Docker container and images, rename the .env file to something like .envOLD, create a new .env file with different values, quit and restart Docker, and rebuild (using --no-cache) and restart the containers, echoing the environmental variables in the  container will give me the old values. I had expected echo to return the new .env file’s values.

Has anyone else seen this, and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: If you're talking about a docker-compose .env file, that file is read by docker compose and what ever is inside your container doesn't matter - how are you starting your containers? Is the file placed together with compose.yaml? Are you looking at the values through a bash shell inside the container running through docker-compose? How are you connecting to that container?

Comment: I am starting my containers with docker-compose up. The .env file is in the same directory as my docker-compose.yaml file. Yes, I am 'echo' ing the values through a bash shell inside the container running through docker-compose.

Comment: I am connecting to that container via Docker Desktop.

Comment: Please don't *tell* us what you are doing, *show* us what you are doing by including your `compose.yaml` file and at least a minimal FastAPI application that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. I added the new environmental variable to the docker-compose.yaml file, so docker knows to load that environmental variable.
2. The .env file is read by docker-compose. In order for changes to the .env file to be read, the containers must be spun up from the command line using docker-compose up.